# How to retrieve updated state from Nanostore in AstroJS / React JSX file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, astrojs

I am trying to receive an updated state from a React component and console.log into an Astro file.

My NanoStore

```
 import { atom } from 'nanostores';

export const DeliveryMethods = atom('');
```

My JSX

```
import { DeliveryMethods } from "../../stores/DeliveryMethods";

const AddToBasket = () => {
  const $DeliveryMethods = useStore(DeliveryMethods); 
  //Got the above from Astro Docs but gives error when trying to use  
  // $DeliveryMethods.set(title). The docs only provide 
  // for true/ false values DeliveryMethods.set(!$DeliveryMethods)} which gives 
  // binding error!

  function setIcon (title) {
    DeliveryMethods.set(title)

    console.log('DeliveryMethods', DeliveryMethods) //Correctly logs updated state
  }

}
```

I've gotten this far with it, triggering setIcon() correctly updates the DeliveryMethod.

However...

```
--- 
import { DeliveryMethods } from "../../../stores/DeliveryMethods";

const DeliveryMethod = DeliveryMethods.get();
console.log(DeliveryMethod) // DOES NOT RETRIEVE THE UPDATED STORE VALUE!
---
```

Here so I receive the initial store value which is set to '' empty string. My AddToBasket component is rendered inside the Astro.js file like below

```
  <AddToBasket client:load/>
```

Comment: The problem is that `DeliveryMethods.get()` in an Astro component gets the initial value? Yes, that's expected, since Astro components only render on the server and never update on the client. You'll need to create another React component for that.

Comment: Oh right so I cant use the updated store in an astro component at all?

Comment: exactly :-) however, you can include a React (or Preact or Solid, or Svelte) component in your Astro component and that will update. see https://docs.astro.build/en/concepts/islands/

Comment: Ah right, yeah I've just turned the astro page into react